# How to Git Ignore Contain "tiu" Word Files

Tags: git, gitignore

the category like:

```
/Script/tiu_adfsfdfdsff.js
/Script/tiu_adfsfdfdsff.js
...
/CSS/tiu_adfsfdfdsff.css
/CSS/tiu_adfsfdfdsff.css
...
```

i want to ignore contain "tiu" files
my .gitignore files is:

```
CSS/tiu*.css
Script/tiu*.js
```

but it don't work?

Comment: Did you already versioned (add+commit) those files?

Comment: If they are already in the index (add without a commit) ignoring them won't work either. You'll need to unstage them first using 

    git reset HEAD

(Your changes won't be lost this way)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to ignore all the tiu* files, use a global pattern (without specifying the directory at first):

```
tui*.css
```

If this does not work, here are the rules for patterns:
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 1):

If they're already added to the repository, you need to remove them from the repo without deleting the files. Do that with:

```
git rm --cached /Script/tiu*
```

That will remove the objects from the repo and the index, but leave the working directory alone. From then on, they should be happily ignored by `git status` and `git add` (and by extension `git commit -a`).